How to listen to webpage button triggered copy events?
I want to create a simple chrome extension that replaces the url that you copied from the "share > Copy link" button of reddit with a short link, but I don't know how to listen to the event of that specific button click or the copy to clipboard event triggered by the button click.
I tried using
document.addEventListener('copy', onCopy, true);

to trigger onCopy whenever something is copied to clipboard, but it seems to only trigger on copy events from context menu, not those from webpage elements.
I'm a beginner in javascript and chrome extension so every advice is appreciated.

You can add a listener to click events instead of copy.
You can then verify the target by using "event.target.closest" and the "share > Copy link" button's ID or data property.

I've determined all "Share > Copy link" buttons to be associated with the selector faceplate-dropdown-menu > faceplate-menu > li.relative.list-none.mt-0.share-menu-copy-link-option, but copying their JS path reveals to me that they are buried under several layers of querySelector and shadowRoot, with the outer layers changing based on post id and webpage format (front page/post/comment section). Is there a nice way to access or listen to clicks on all these buttons with the same selector or do I need to loop through all layers and hard code based on if it's front page/post/comment section?
